# AngularJs Filter Not Array in Nested Object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a nested JSON data. I am writing an object to a table by using ng-repeat from this JSON data. But I want to filter by a property this ng-repeat. How can I do this.

Sample:

```
<tr ng-repeat="i in inspections.analizFirst">
    <td>{{$index+1}}</td><td>{{i.analiz}}</td><td>{{i.poi_adi}}</td><td>{{i.mesafe}}</td>
</tr>
```

It works without filter. But I need to filter like `ng-repeat="i in inspections.analizFirst | filter:{analiz:'ulasim analizi'}"`

Comment: what is the problem with `ng-repeat="i in inspections.analizFirst | filter:{analiz:'ulasim analizi'}"` , you get an error ?

Comment: The error is [filter notarray]

Answer (score 0):

#### Use controller:

You can filter the data inside your controller and then refer to the filtered object in the html. It's usually more readable when you place all business logic in the controller

#### Create your own filter:

If you are planning to use this filter in multiple in the application, maybe its a good idea to create a new filter:

```
appModule.filter('myFilter', function() {
  return function(orginalList, arg1, arg2) {
    var filteredObject = [];
    orginalList.forEach(function(e) {
      if(e.analiz === arg1)
           filteredObject.push(e) 
    })
    return filteredObject;
   };
 })
```

html

```
<tr ng-repeat="i in inspections.analizFirst | myFilter:'ulasim analizi'">
  <td>{{$index+1}}</td><td>{{i.analiz}}</td><td>{{i.poi_adi}}</td><td>
 {{i.mesafe}}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="i in inspections.analizFirst | filter:'ulasim analizi'">
    <td>{{$index+1}}</td><td>{{i.analiz}}</td><td>{{i.poi_adi}}</td><td>{{i.mesafe}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Not working ->  Error: [filter:notarray] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4/filter/notarray?.....